# Failing to demote domain controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I have 2 Domain Controllers 1 is a 2008 R2 and the other is a 2016. I am trying to demote the 2008 and then I get the following error. I need advice [image]

Issue is it is saying it could not transfer remaining data in directory partition.

Comment: Looks like you did not transfer FSMO roles to the new DC. Check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/255504/using-ntdsutil-exe-to-transfer-or-seize-fsmo-roles-to-a-domain-control

Comment: I went through and applied all Transfer infrastructure master - Make connected server the infrastructure master
 Transfer naming master        - Make connected server the naming master
 Transfer PDC                  - Make connected server the PDC
 Transfer RID master           - Make connected server the RID master
 Transfer schema master        - Make connected server the schema master

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2694933/dcpromo-demotion-fails-if-unable-to-contact-the-dns-infrastructure-mas

Comment: You don't need to manually transfer the FSMO roles. A DC demotion will gracefully transfer any FSMO roles held by the server being demoted. Have a look at the article I linked and see if that's relevant.